# Windows 7 copy files dialog - option to replace on CRC mismatch?

Tags: windows-7, crc

Started using 7 : nice of them to ask me if I want my files to be replaced/skipped/renamed but very poor implementation : is there a way to tell windows to immediately replace files on CRC match and only ask on CRC mismatch ? An option to log the replacements ? An option to rename the *old* file instead of the new one ? An option to customize the naming scheme ? An option to replace older/newer files only ?
A third party utility ?

EDIT : 3 years after and I actually haven't found an answer to this

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me that what you're actually after is [Teracopy](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php),  I know it does CRC checking, but I think it may do some of the other things your were asking for.

It can act as a direct replacement for the Windows Copy window if you want it to.

-=EDIT=-

As it seems that you've experienced the limitations of TeraCopy I've found a few other alternatives:

[Copywhiz](http://www.conceptworld.com/Copywhiz) is payware, but has some [auto-renaming features](http://www.conceptworld.com/Copywhiz/Auto-Rename-Files-With-Duplicate-Names?Rewind=1) that look like what you're asking for.  Most of it's other features seem to match up with what you're wanting too, such as [copying only new or modifed files](http://www.conceptworld.com/Copywhiz/Copy-Only-New-Or-Modifed-Files) and [log file creation](http://www.conceptworld.com/Copywhiz/Other-File-Copy-Features#PageSectionHeader).

[TotalCopy](http://ranvik.net/totalcopy/) seems to be a rather simplistic replacement, mainly catering for poor connections with it's auto-pause and restart feature.

[KillCopy](http://killprog.narod.ru/killcopye.html) appears to have a slightly better configuration set, but looks like it lacks the auto-renaming feature you want.  I looks to be able to log the copy procedure.

[SuperCopier](http://supercopier.sfxteam.org/) looks a bit simple, but may have some of the features you require... at least the changelog reads "File collision handling improvement: it is now possible to rename and to overwrite only different files"

Other than that I'd recommend getting a copy of [SyncBack Freeware Edition](http://www.2brightsparks.com/freeware/) as it may have all of the features you require and can be set up to schedule the copies so that you know the files are always in sync.

Comment: I have been using teracopy for years with XP - it is slower than the 7 copy machine I read - and anyway no - it is very annoyingly coded - custom rename options ? nope - you can't even choose to rename the older file. And the user interface sucks - on collision a very small fixed width win pops up and one has to always move a slider to see what collided. No undo option for cut (windows has that). The list goes on and on. See I know this app too well - any others ? Mind you it was the best I found for xp - I just hoped 7 would be decent - well...

Comment: Added a bundle of other suggestions.  Not tried them all, but they at least look reasonable as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks - I had tried many ones but they lacked basic features like drag and drop files to their GUI (SuperCopier FastCopy CopyHandler RichCopy - maybe changed in newer versions) - that's why I ended up with tera copy - I'll heck the ones you posted.
Thanks :)